# Sorting and Filtering on a Calculated Field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I am currently using [NonFactors/MVC6-Grid](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC6.Grid) to represent data on my index page for a fairly basic CRUD app built with .NET Core 2.0 & MVC. I have a model with several fields, a few of which are calculated fields.

Sorting and Filtering with the MVC grid works really well, even with > 550,000 records. However, when I am trying to sort and filter on one of the calculated fields, there is a great decrease in performance (it takes about 45 seconds). This isn't the end of the world, but I would like to know if there is a way to increase the performance of calculated fields?

I am pretty sure that the performance drop is either due to the lack of an index on the calculated fields, or the fact that each record's calculated property is re-calculated and *then* sorted/filtered, or both.

If anyone has any insight on where the bottleneck could be and if there was a way I could increase performance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean by "calculated field". Is this a property mapped to a calculated column in the database table? Or is just a get only property doing some calculation from other properties of the object? Because in the second case EFC simply retrieves the whole table data from database and performs filtering / sorting client side, which should explain why it is so slow.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry for the lack of clarity. I am talking about a property that is calculated based on other properties on the object. I believe I will try to implement server side / persisted columns for the required calculations

Comment: Then avoid that property and try to use the corresponding expression. Otherwise EF Core will use client evaluation. Which may not be a big deal for sorting (except if you also do pagination), but for filtering that would be a real bottleneck.

Comment: Link no longer exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SQL Documentation

- A computed column cannot be used as a DEFAULT or FOREIGN KEY
  constraint definition or with a NOT NULL constraint definition.
  However, if the computed column value is defined by a deterministic
  expression and the data type of the result is allowed in index
  columns, a computed column can be used as a key column in an index or
  as part of any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint. For example, if the
  table has integer columns a and b, the computed column a + b may be
  indexed, but computed column a + DATEPART(dd, GETDATE()) cannot be
  indexed, because the value might change in subsequent invocations.

So you may be able to set up an index...depends on the calculation.

Also depending on the version of SQL server you are using....you can mark the column as PERSISTED.

Sorting and Filtering on the SQL Server with indexes will be much faster than client side as previously suggested

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that this existed.  The required calculations are relatively simple so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You get the records from DB, filter based on the condition and do the calculation in C# code, then map it to your list of Dto and apply sorting. And finally, return the list of Dto to client-side code.